What is the upper bound for black hole entropy derived from in the Bekenstein bound?
From several unrelated sources (such as Scott Aaronson's discussion of hypercomputation or this article about a bound on the number of degrees of freedom of any theory with a positive cosmological constant), I have bumped into the claim that the universe contains a finite amount of information (on the order of $10^{122}$ bits), backed by references to the Bekenstein bound.
I followed the references to Bekenstein's original article. The logic seems to be approximately this:

General relativity theorems show that (classically) the total area of black hole event horizons cannot decrease.
If we assume that black holes have zero entropy, then we can break the second law of thermodynamics by throwing matter with some entropy into a black hole.
Therefore, it is natural to extend the concept of entropy by adding a contribution from black holes, whose entropy should be directly proportional to their surface area.
The proportionality constant $\frac{S}{A}$, in Planck units, is $\frac{1}{4}$. (This is the step I am having trouble with.)
When a black hole absorbs an object of energy $E$ and radius $R$, its area must (for general-relativity reasons) increase by at least $8 \pi ER$. This increases the black hole's entropy by $2 \pi ER$. For the second law not to be violated, the body cannot have more entropy than this. This creates a bound on $\frac{S}{E}$ that we can then plug values for the entire observable universe into, getting the $10^{122}$ bits.

But I am having trouble tracking down where that proportionality constant came from. Bekenstein provides three references for it: Ref. 1, Ref. 3, Ref. 6.

In Ref. 3, Bekenstein calculates it from a thought experiment involving dropping a single particle into a black hole. He makes the assumption that the information associated with the particle is at least one bit (as the answer to the question "does the particle exist?"), but he himself considers this a lower bound, with the true value probably not far away, but unspecified.
Ref. 6 is also earlier work by Bekenstein; it links to Ref. 3 and makes the additional observation that a higher proportionality constant would forbid particles from being captured by a black hole reversibly (with $\Delta S_g = 0$, where $S_g$ is the generalised entropy, that is, classical entropy plus black hole entropy). This provides some plausibility-based argument for this precise value, but not a derivation from uncontroversial facts.
Ref. 1 seems to be the original derivation of Hawking radiation; it's above my skill level and I cannot see whether at any point there is a similar assumption made.

In particular, I could imagine the proportionality constant being bigger. There are many thought experiments considered in these papers and their references that show various processes (which involve dropping various kinds of particles or radiation into a black hole) adhere to the bound, but they would also adhere to the same bound if the proportionality constant were artificially increased tenfold. To disprove this possibility, one would instead want some opposite process, where the black hole's surface area decreases while classical entropy increases. I believe Hawking radiation is of this nature. Is there a better, less plausibility-based assumption in that derivation?
These papers are also rather old, perhaps there have been better treatments since then.
My question is: Does Hawking radiation, or some other thought experiment, provide an upper bound on the entropy of black holes? If so, where in the derivation does one find the upper bound on the amount of information? How is the link between black hole area and bits of information established? Does it rest on a similar assumption of "one particle, one bit"?
Note: The question about the proportionality constant has been asked before here, but I hope you agree my question is far more focused and would not be likely to find answers there.

Hawking's Euclidean derivation with Page is simpler than his original Minkowskian derivation. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/647108/

Real blackholes, if they exist, have to be more complicated than the idealized featureless blackholes in vacuum. In particular, on can't just get rid of something by throwing it in. Lots of mass thrown its way should hover over the horizon, slowed down, with non-zero entropy. So that entropy does not get "lost from the universe" in any finite time; it just concentrates near the horizon. This hovering entropy cannot be proportional to black hole area as given by the usual formula(proportional to mass squared), because the hovering entropy depends on thermodynamic state of the hovering bodies.

The conclusion about finite number of bits is also dubious even for the idealized black hole with no stuff hovering over the horizon. Mass is a real number, and by getting a large enough number of digits of this number, we can get arbitrarily large number of bits. Not that it is easy to measure more than few of them, but there is no principle forcing finite number of possible masses to exist.

@JánLalinský To your second comment: Some would argue (Scott Aaronson does so here, for example: https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/npcomplete.pdf) that the Bekenstein bound actually does mean we couldn't measure mass (or any continuous value) to arbitrary precision. I for one would be very careful about claiming to measure anything to 500 significant digits, because then literally any unknown effect might interfere.

@JánLalinský To your first comment: Some of the papers I linked mention something similar to this idea: the entropy of a black hole is huge but finite and microscopically comes precisely from the matter "hovering" on the horizon. Black holes actually attain the Bekenstein bound, so during gravitational collapse, entropy rises dramatically to the maximum possible, regardless of the original entropy of whatever fell in. It seems to me that you're actually in agreement with the "idealised" view.

If entropy is due to matter hovering over the horizon, it cannot be a simple function of the hole mass. Entropy is function of thermodynamic state variables, not of mass. One can have the same mass with zero entropy and with immense entropy.

My point is the idea of mass can be any real number is established and accepted much more than the idea mass can only attain discrete states - that is a rather speculative idea. Even in quantum theory, energy and mass are real, continuous variables. That one cannot measure 500 digits of it is a different matter. Not being able to measure something does not mean it does not exist in the theory.

The idea that there is only finite number of bits is just a modern computational repackage of the old idea that the world is actually discrete or the idea the world is a discrete state computer. Both relativity and quantum theory beg to differ - time and space are continuous. The argument "otherwise holographic principle would not work" is very weak, because there is no real need for such principle, it's just an interesting idea that may not realize in physical world.

The lack of any known discreteness in the universe is a nitpick comment. Bekenstein's ideas absolutely do imply that the maximum density of states for a given region grows like the area.

@JánLalinský This is turning into a dogmatic argument. My question comes from genuine confusion, which I'm trying to clarify by tracking where the bound comes from. Ján, you are saying the holographic principle is "just an interesting idea that may not realize in physical world". Connor, you're saying it absolutely does work. I'm trying to follow the logic of why it should work. It seems that Hawking radiation is key to it, but I still don't know where within that mechanism one gets the relationship between the entropy and area. Do you have any references that could clarify this?

@ConnorBehan Also tagging you (apparently it's not possible to tag multiple users at once).

@ConnorBehan I did not say there is lack of any known discreteness, plenty of things are discrete. Just not the space of quantum states.

@ConnorBehan density of states counts usually only Hamiltonian eigenstates, it ignores superpositions. If we're talking about encoding information or integer numbers in physical states, there is a whole lot more states than those counted in density of states.

I posted a link with references. If you believe Hawking's $S = A/4G$ is correct then a non-black hole with area $A$ must have $S < A/4G$. If it had more, turning it into a black hole by adding mass would violate the second law. And yes, density of states counts the dimension of the Hilbert space, $\log_2$ of which is the number of qubits worth of information.

@ConnorBehan state of one qubit takes, in general, infinite number of bits to describe; in case of spin 1/2, the state lives on a continuous 3D unit sphere. The fact one cannot measure these bits by one quantum measurement of one qubit is a different matter. This means the unknown stored information in the system is unrelated to density of states or thermodynamic entropy. The number of "qubits worth of information" is not the number of bits encoded in the physical state.

"object of energy E and radius R" ??   R is the radius of the black hole, not the object.

Seems like basic thermodynamics. Heat is transferred reversibly from the black hole to some stuff that is at a temperature infinitesimally less than black hole's temperature. Calculate the entropy increase of stuff when black hole has no energy left.  That is the upper bound.

@stuffu This avoids the problem by assuming that a black hole has a clear temperature. But to derive that you need all the Hawking radiation stuff, which is what I'm struggling with.

Unfortunately, those heuristic arguments are just that -- heuristics. If you actually want to derive the numeric factors, there's no alternative to going through a proper derivation of Hawking radiation. There are a couple ways to shortcut the calculation (e.g. by making an analogy with the Unruh effet) but no way to remove the math entirely.

Specifically, the number you need to get is the temperature of Hawking radiation from a black hole, which is $1 / (8 \pi M)$. From that, you can deduce the entropy using basic thermodynamics, without having to resort to any arguments involving "bits" or whatever else.

Also, because there's always been massive public interest in Hawking radiation, you're not going to find anything good on that subject through an internet search. 99.9% of the results are going to be extremely heuristic, sometimes nonsensical arguments designed for nonphysicists to find vaguely plausible. The real calculation is done right in Hawking's original papers 50 years ago. Some more modern graduate textbooks cover it too, but they essentially give the same argument. There's also a more modern picture involving tunneling, but it's also technical.

one particle, one (q)bit is just basic structure of a Hilbert space for free fermion field (in occupancy number representation any given field mode can have either 0 or 1 occupancy due to Pauli exclusion principle). For other types of fields (bosons, multi-species, interacting) the actual numbers are of course different.

An reasonably clear explanation is given in General Relativity and its Applications
Black Holes, Compact Stars and Gravitational Waves
,By Valeria Ferrari, Leonardo Gualtieri, Paolo Pani, see chapters 20.3 and 20.4.
In a nutshell:

The fact that the area of a black hole always increases can be compared to how the entropy of a thermodynamic system is always increasing. This lead to conjecture that S is proportional to A for a black hole. So $S = \alpha A$ for an unspecified constant $\alpha$, the analogue of the second law of thermodynamics. Also one can derive the first law of black hole thermodynamic relating $dM$ and $dA$.
Bekenstein imagines dropping a massive particle into a black hole. The minimum amount of entropy increase is going to be $ln2$, that is 1 bit of information. This means that $\alpha \approx ln2 / dA_{min}$.
By the uncertainty principle there is an uncertainty in the position of the particle, with associated proper length of the order of the Compton wavelength. From this one can compute the associated $dM_{min}$, by requiring that the proper distance between the horizon and the point in which
the particle is released equates the Compton wavelength.
Now using the first law one can plug $dM_{min}$ and $dA_{min}$ and can find that $\alpha \approx 1 / \hbar$, but the precise factor is still not fixed. One can also compute the associated temperature, in term of $\alpha$.
Hawking performed a calculation in QFT in curved space time to show that a scalar field coupled to the black hole effectively behave as if the black hole is emitting radiation, as a black body of temperature T. From the temperature found one can see that the numeric value of $\alpha$ is 1/4.


To be picky, it's certainly not true that the minimum change in entropy is 1 bit. In information theory, one considers smaller entropy changes all the time. For example, if a biased coin comes up heads 90% of the time, the entropy associated with its result is $-0.9 , \text{log}_2 , 0.9 - 0.1 , \text{log}_2 , 0.1 = 0.47$ bits.

The OP asks I am having trouble tracking down where that proportionality constant came from
You don't need Hawking radiation to make a semi-classical argument why the proportionality constant is $1/4$ rather than something else.
As @Rexcircus above says, we can conjecture that entropy $\propto$ area. The surface area of a sphere: $S=4\pi r^2$. If we consider the smallest semi-classical radius, the Planck length, and use natural units so $L_{Planck}=1$ we have $S=4 \pi$. One unit of entropy for one unit of area. Nice.
PS - In a semi-classical analysis, the Planck length plays the role of a minimal length. But don't take my word for it, you can read this.
However, the Schwarzschild radius of the smallest semi-classical mass (Planck mass $M_P$) black hole (which is a sphere) is: $R=2GM_P/c^2$. In natural units $G=\hbar=c=1$ so $M_{P}=1$ and then $R=2$. Still, this Planck mass black hole must exhibit the minimum semi-classical entropy we just figured out. How to do that? Well, we need a proportionality constant, call it $1/P$. As we can see below, the formula only works when $P=4$, i.e. $1/P=1/4$. Job done.
\begin{equation} 
S= 4\pi = 4\pi R^2 \frac{1}{P}=\frac{A_H}{4}
\end{equation}
PPS. For those who doubt that the Planck mass is the correct mass to use in a semi-classical analysis, read this answer aka the mass at which it happens is about the Planck mass
Bonus: If you want to know where the $S \sim 10^{122}$ of the Universe comes from, it is the entropy (nats) of the cosmic event horizon, which you can read about in this wonderful paper by Lineweaver (Eqn 49). The connection between bits and nats in in my answer here.

As to whoever gave this a negative vote - show me the error in this argument. Pfft.

I'd guess the phrase "smallest semi-classical radius, the Planck length" is rather problematic and hides a lot of assumptions. This is a reasonable dimensional analysis argument, so no downvote from me, but it doesn't exactly give one an understanding...

@Kotlopu - in a semi-classical analysis, i.e. until a better theory of quantum gravity is devised, the Planck length is the best estimate we have for a minimum length.
